# How to create a pop up window asking for input using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ember.js

My index.html code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/one.css">
</head>
<body>

<!--Script1-->

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div id="W">
<h1> Welcome </h1>
</div>

<div id="section1">
<h2>   {{#link-to 'DINESH'}} DINESH {{/link-to}}  </h2>
</div>

<div id="section">
<h2> {{#link-to 'HOME'}} HOME {{/link-to}} </h2> 
</div>

<div id="section2">
<h2> {{#link-to 'CLICK'}} CLICK {{/link-to}} </h2> 
</div> 

 {{outlet}}

  </script>

  <!--Script2-->

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id='HOME'>
  <div class-'HOME'>
  <p>
    This is a sample site for practicing Ember.js 
  </p>
  </script>

  <!--Script3-->

   <script type="text/x-handlebars" id='DINESH'>
  <div class-'DINESH'>
  <p>
     I welcome you to my page.. keep in touch......!!!!!
  </p>
  VIDIYAL
<br>

   Being the "Director of Community Service" in Rotaract Club of Future League, I organised a project called "VIDIYAL" where i taught basic computer knowledge to Orphanage Students. 
  </script>

  <!--Script4-->

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id='CLICK'>

<div class-'CLICK'>
<p> Click the button to display the information which you want: </p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="CLICK"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}



  </script>


  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-v2.0.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <!-- to activate the test runner, add the "?test" query string parameter -->
  <script src="tests/runner.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and app.js code is

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function()
{
    this.resource('HOME');
    this.resource('DINESH');
    this.resource('CLICK');
});
```

If i click it should display a pop-up window asking for my name ("Enter your name").

I am a student who is very new to programming. So kindly explain me as simple as you can.

Comment: You could use [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt)

Comment: Dear MLeFevre, Thanks but where should i add that code?? And I need  not create any model for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in pure javascript. `prompt()` method will do this for you. 
Check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp)

If you want to do this in Ember.js, you need to open a modal, on the user click.
Created a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rocky_217/uxa38xjz/4/

Comment: No dude.. I needed to do in ember js only. Kindly tell how to do it in ember js.

Comment: You need to open a modal. Check http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/

Comment: Exactly I tried this.. but i got the same code when i Selected the click button. Now how should I connect it with my app.js file?

Comment: Mr Dev, now its working. but the problem is, the pop up page displays in index.html page.                                                     <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="INDEX">
    <h4>The current name is: {{name}}</h4>
    {{outlet}}
    <button {{action 'openModal' 'modal' model}}>Change Name</button>
  </script>....... when i change index to click.. still its asking for name, but it does not display the name which i enter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use prompt() function in jquery or js to receive input in popup. check out the code -:

```
<script>

var childAge =  prompt("Enter Child  age")
alert(childAge);

</script>
```

Comment: Dear Akash. okay but how can i link this with my app.js file? kindly explain me in detail..

Comment: @DineshT first of all thanks for giving +10, ok you can either paste above code directly in your html page or in app.js write var name = prompt("Enter your name") and user name variable accordingly as user input will be stored inside. please make me more clear what is inside app.js if you feel cumbersome.